# javascript Confirmation Dialog in capybara webkit driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

So I want to test a user deleting their account using capybara and rspec:

```
scenario "User wants to delete their account" do
  click_link "Account"
  click_link "Delete My Account"
  expect(page).to have_text("You're account was deleted.")
end
```

Only problem is a js confirmation dialog appears when a user clicks 'delete my account'. To confirm this dialog I did the following:

1. Install capybara-webkit
2. add `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit` to my spec_helper.rb
3. add `:js => true` to `scenario "User wants to delete their account" do`.

Now nothing seems to work with the addition of `:js => true`. I am getting the error `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find link "Account"` and before it was working fine, does `js: true` interfere with these capybara methods? Is my config wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Importantly, the link in question was inside a dropdown that was not visible without a mouse hover event. To solve the issue I opened the dropdown with javascript before I clicked the link.

```
page.execute_script('$(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle");')
```

Answer (score 0):

`:js => true` tells Capybara to use the JavaScript driver for your spec; it's needed to run pages that have to execute JavaScript as part of their functionality.  In your case, it would be needed for the JS confirmation dialog.

BUT...there's a couple of other things to note:

1. Your link is titled "Account" above and your looking for "Account Settings".  Is that a typo?
2. I don't think you'll be able to interact with a vanilla browser confirmation dialog (i.e. alert box with confirm buttons).  I know you can't when using the Poltergeist driver

Comment: 1. Yes that was a typo thankyou. 2. This doesn't explain why I am getting an error for something unrelated to javascript, capybara can't find the link when ```js: true```. Is there something wrong with my config?

Comment: You probably need to look into putting the js driver into a debug mode, so you can see what's happening on the page.  I know how to do this with poltergeist, but not capybara-webkit.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the visit path, before clicking to 'Delete My Account'.

```
scenario "User wants to delete their account" do
  click_link "Account"
  expect(current_path).to eq '/my_accout'
  click_link "Delete My Account"
  expect(page).to have_text("You're account was deleted.")
end
```

Comment: I have already tried this, good technique for diagnosing problems though, thanks

Comment: If you are confirmed that it gets access to my account page, there must be a link with text 'Delete My Account'. You can use 'click_on', instead of 'click_link'.